# How to check the current firebase user and open diffrent activities as per login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**I just want to open the activity as per state of firebase auth **

if(user already Logged in)
If the user is Customer then go to = Mainactivity .
If the user is Admin then go to = AdminNavigationActivity

the problem is what its always open go to the main activity when i opened the app in second time its doesn't check the user state . or which user is logged in.

Help me Sorry for my Bad english.

```
          mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
                  //  String name = user.getDisplayName();
                    String email = user.getEmail();


                if (email=="admin@gmail.com") {
                       Intent admin_intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminNavigationActivity.class);
                        startActivity(admin_intent);
                        finish();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                    }
                }

            }


        };

        linkSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        reset_pass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // resetPassword();
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (txtEmail.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    txtEmail.setError("This field is required!");
                } else if (!isValidEmail(txtEmail.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    txtEmail.setError("This is not a valid email!");
                } else if (txtPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    txtPassword.setError("This field is required!");
                } else {


                    progressDialog.setTitle("Login");
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
                    progressDialog.show();
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
                    password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                if (txtEmail.getText().toString().equals("admin@gmail.com"))//&& txtPassword.getText().toString().equals("8605357562"))
                                {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminNavigationActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressDialog.hide();
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }

            }
        });

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this code:

```
      if (user != null) {
                // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
              //  String name = user.getDisplayName();
                String email = user.getEmail();


            if (email=="admin@gmail.com") {
                   Intent admin_intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminNavigationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(admin_intent);
                    finish();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                }
            }
```

so if email is not admin then it will always go to the `mainActivity`.

Also if you close the app remove it from background also. To do that click the button next to the `home` button and remove it then login again.

Or log out the user. Do a sign out button and give it this code on button click(and go to right activity):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

change this:

```
  if (txtEmail.getText().toString().equals("admin@gmail.com"))
```

to this:

```
 if (email.equals("admin@gmail.com"))
```

Comment: I already written that lines in my code . I debug and check when I logged in the state is always goes to the main activity and when I restart my app it's goes to main activity not to admin activity.

Comment: do a sign out button

Comment: Not working i changed  if (email.equals("admin@gmail.com")) but its worked at once when login in 2nd time its not worked its goes to the mainActivity  i logged in using admin@gmail.com

Comment: inside  `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` add after `finish()` Log.d("email is", email); and tell me the answer. If it worked once it should be everytime there is something else wrong then

Comment: its doesnt worked.. its always go to the launcher activity , i changed lancher activity as LoginActivity its goes to the login page afte close and reopen the app

Comment: check updated answer, launcher should be mainactivity then go to loginactivity there should be a button(btnlogin) you click it and you go to next activity example admin one

Comment: if the above activity is login activity then user has to be equal to null since he is not logged in yet, so there is no user..

Comment: I saved data in database after get data and solved it ... 

Thanks for help

Comment: Sorry brother I can't because I need perfect answer for it